# Crystal Reports Record Selection and Summary Field conflict

Tags: crystal-reports, report, reporting, crystal-reports-2008

I am really new to Crystal Reports and I am looking for any suggestions on how to approach the following issue:

I currently have a report that uses a record selection to limit the results by date. I would like to include in this same report a summary a total count of all the records (ignoring the record restriction). Unfortunately (although somewhat expected), the summary calculates the total after the record restriction is applied. Is there any way to get around this? In case my question is a bit unclear I've included a generic example below:

- I have a report that pulls info from a database with a total of 10 records.
- I select a specific date range, and it only returns 3 records
- I would like to include in the report footer that 3/10 records are getting returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bit tricky to perform in crystal reports as record selection is compulsory applied. However you can overcome this by using sub report.

Calculate the report footer using report.

This will surely work

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. I actually tried this before but I must have configured the sub-report incorrectly. After playing around with the sub-report a bit per your suggestion, I was able to get the total count without the restriction.